# Java DataInputStream sometimes returns empty

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, datainputstream, printstream

I currently am making a messaging application which I will also add encryption to later.
I have a server which opens a socket and waits for clients to connect. Once client connects, it creates a new thread for that client. and then waits for messages etc.

The problem I am having is that when I try to send the public key exponent and modulus to the client, the Client is unable to use `datainputstream(clientSocket.getInputStream()).readLine`.

The sending of the exponent and Modulus happen on `line 173 and 174`.The receiving on the client side happens on line `125 and 136`.

Server sending the data.

    `os.println(modulusMap.get(requestName));
    os.println(exponentMap.get(requestName));`

Client attempting to write the data to a variable:

    `pubModulusString = is.readLine().trim();

    BigInteger pubModulus = new BigInteger(pubModulusString);

    HashMap<String, BigInteger> modulusMap = new HashMap<String, BigInteger>();
    modulusMap.put(message.substring(1), pubModulus);

    String pubExponentString = is.readLine();`

I have tested the sending of data as just a print stream and it is working perfectly. It is only when I try to read the data and save it into a variable that the problem occurs`(line 125 and 136)`.

Majority of the time the `readLine()` reads the modulus as just blank, but sometimes it will successfully read it. I cannot find a pattern to when it is successful and when it is not.

What is also very weird is that I use the exact same code to send data from client to server. This can be seen on Client side `line 89 and 91`. And the server receives the data on `lines 113 and 119`.

Thank you for any help or ideas in advance.

Posted below is the full code for any 1 that is kind enough and has the time to run it.

Server:

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.*;



/*
 * A chat server that delivers public and private messages.
 */
public class MultiThreadChatServerSync {

  // The server socket.
  private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
  // The client socket.
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;

  // This chat server can accept up to maxClientsCount clients' connections.
  private static final int maxClientsCount = 10;
  private static final clientThread[] threads = new clientThread[maxClientsCount];

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    // The default port number.
    int portNumber = 2222;
    if (args.length < 1) {
      System.out.println("Usage: java MultiThreadChatServerSync <portNumber>\n"
          + "Now using port number=" + portNumber);
    } else {
      portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[0]).intValue();
    }

    /*
     * Open a server socket on the portNumber (default 2222). Note that we can
     * not choose a port less than 1023 if we are not privileged users (root).
     */
    try {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }

    /*
     * Create a client socket for each connection and pass it to a new client
     * thread.
     */
    while (true) {
      try {
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] == null) {
            (threads[i] = new clientThread(clientSocket, threads)).start();
            break;
          }
        }
        if (i == maxClientsCount) {
          PrintStream os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
          os.println("Server too busy. Try later.");
          os.close();
          clientSocket.close();
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
  }
}

/*
 * The chat client thread. This client thread opens the input and the output
 * streams for a particular client, ask the client's name, informs all the
 * clients connected to the server about the fact that a new client has joined
 * the chat room, and as long as it receive data, echos that data back to all
 * other clients. The thread broadcast the incoming messages to all clients and
 * routes the private message to the particular client. When a client leaves the
 * chat room this thread informs also all the clients about that and terminates.
 */
class clientThread extends Thread {

  private String clientName = null;
  private DataInputStream is = null;
  private BufferedReader inputLine = null;
  private PrintStream os = null;
  private Socket clientSocket = null;
  private final clientThread[] threads;
  private int maxClientsCount;

  public clientThread(Socket clientSocket, clientThread[] threads) {
    this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    this.threads = threads;
    maxClientsCount = threads.length;
  }

  public void run() {
    int maxClientsCount = this.maxClientsCount;
    clientThread[] threads = this.threads;
    HashMap<String, BigInteger> modulusMap = new HashMap<String, BigInteger>();
    HashMap<String, BigInteger> exponentMap = new HashMap<String, BigInteger>();
    try {
      /*
       * Create input and output streams for this client.
       */
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      inputLine = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String name;
      while (true) {
        os.println("Enter your name.");
        name = is.readLine().trim();

        String pubModulusString = is.readLine().trim();
        BigInteger pubModulus = new BigInteger(pubModulusString);


        modulusMap.put(name, pubModulus);

        String pubExponentString = is.readLine().trim();
        BigInteger pubExponent = new BigInteger(pubExponentString);


        exponentMap.put(name, pubExponent);


        if (name.indexOf('@') == -1) {
          break;
        } else {
          os.println("The name should not contain '@' character.");
        }
      }

      /* Welcome the new the client. */
      os.println("Welcome " + name
          + " to our chat room.\nTo leave enter /quit in a new line.");
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] == this) {
            clientName = "@" + name;
            break;
          }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this) {
            threads[i].os.println("*** A new user " + name
                + " entered the chat room !!! ***");
          }
        }








        }
      /* Start the conversation. */
      while (true) {
        String line = is.readLine();
        if (line.startsWith("/quit")) {
          break;
        }


        if (line.startsWith("!")){


        String requestName;
            requestName = line;
            requestName = requestName.substring(1);

            os.println(modulusMap.get(requestName));
            os.println(exponentMap.get(requestName));

        }
        else {



        /* If the message is private sent it to the given client. */
        if (line.startsWith("@")) {
          String[] words = line.split("\\s", 2);
          if (words.length > 1 && words[1] != null) {
            words[1] = words[1].trim();
            if (!words[1].isEmpty()) {
              synchronized (this) {
                for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
                  if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this
                      && threads[i].clientName != null
                      && threads[i].clientName.equals(words[0])) {
                    threads[i].os.println("<" + name + "> " + words[1]);
                    /*
                     * Echo this message to let the client know the private
                     * message was sent.
                     */
                    this.os.println(">" + name + "> " + words[1]);
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        } else {
          /* The message is public, broadcast it to all other clients. */
          synchronized (this) {
              this.os.println("Please select who you wish to message by typing '@username *Your Message*'");
          }
        }
        }
      }
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] != null && threads[i] != this
              && threads[i].clientName != null) {
            threads[i].os.println("*** The user " + name
                + " is leaving the chat room !!! ***");
          }
        }
      }
      os.println("*** Bye " + name + " ***");

      /*
       * Clean up. Set the current thread variable to null so that a new client
       * could be accepted by the server.
       */
      synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 0; i < maxClientsCount; i++) {
          if (threads[i] == this) {
            threads[i] = null;
          }
        }
      }
      /*
       * Close the output stream, close the input stream, close the socket.
       */
      is.close();
      os.close();
      clientSocket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
  }
}
```

Client

```
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.crypto.*;



public class MultiThreadChatClient implements Runnable {

  // The client socket
  private static Socket clientSocket = null;
  // The output stream
  private static PrintStream os = null;
  // The input stream
  private static DataInputStream is = null;

  private static BufferedReader inputLine = null;
  private static boolean closed = false;


  private static final String PUBLIC_KEY_FILE = "Public.key"; 
  private static final String PRIVATE_KEY_FILE = "Private.key"; 

  public static void main(String[] args) {



    // The default port.
    int portNumber = 2222;
    // The default host.
String host = "192.168.0.16";

    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.out
          .println("Usage: java MultiThreadChatClient <host> <portNumber>\n"
              + "Now using host=" + host + ", portNumber=" + portNumber);
    } else {
      host = args[0];
      portNumber = Integer.valueOf(args[1]).intValue();
    }

    /*
     * Open a socket on a given host and port. Open input and output streams.
     */
    try {
      clientSocket = new Socket(host, portNumber);
      inputLine = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      os = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
      System.err.println("Don't know about host " + host);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to the host "
          + host);
    }

    /*
     * If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data to the
     * socket we have opened a connection to on the port portNumber.
     */
    if (clientSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
      try {

        /* Create a thread to read from the server. */
        new Thread(new MultiThreadChatClient()).start();

        String myName = inputLine.readLine();
        os.println(myName.trim());

        try { 
           KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA"); 
           keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048); //1024 used for normal securities 
           KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(); 
           PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic(); 
           PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate(); 

           //Pullingout parameters which makes up Key 
           KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA"); 
           RSAPublicKeySpec rsaPubKeySpec = (RSAPublicKeySpec) keyFactory.getKeySpec(publicKey, RSAPublicKeySpec.class); 
           RSAPrivateKeySpec rsaPrivKeySpec = (RSAPrivateKeySpec) keyFactory.getKeySpec(privateKey, RSAPrivateKeySpec.class); 
           os.println(rsaPubKeySpec.getModulus());
           System.out.println(rsaPubKeySpec.getModulus());
           os.println(rsaPubKeySpec.getPublicExponent()); 

           FileOutputStream fos = null; 
           ObjectOutputStream oos = null;

           fos = new FileOutputStream(PUBLIC_KEY_FILE); 
           oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos)); 

           oos.writeObject(rsaPubKeySpec.getModulus());
           oos.writeObject(rsaPubKeySpec.getPublicExponent());

           oos.close();
           fos.close();

           fos = new FileOutputStream(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE); 
           oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(fos)); 

           oos.writeObject(rsaPrivKeySpec.getModulus());
           oos.writeObject(rsaPrivKeySpec.getPrivateExponent());

           oos.close();
           fos.close();

          } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) { 
           e.printStackTrace(); 
          }catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) { 
           e.printStackTrace(); 
          } 

        while (!closed) {
        String message = inputLine.readLine();
            if (message.startsWith("!")){
                os.println(message.trim());

                String pubModulusString = is.readLine().trim();


                BigInteger pubModulus = new BigInteger(pubModulusString);

                HashMap<String, BigInteger> modulusMap = new HashMap<String, BigInteger>();

                modulusMap.put(message.substring(1), pubModulus);


                String pubExponentString = is.readLine();
                BigInteger pubExponent = new BigInteger(pubExponentString);

                HashMap<String, BigInteger> exponentMap = new HashMap<String, BigInteger>();

                exponentMap.put(message.substring(1), pubExponent);


                System.out.println(modulusMap.get(message.substring(1)) + " Hi");
                System.out.println(exponentMap.get(message.substring(1)) + "asdk");

            }
            else{
                // INSERT ENCRYPTION ON "message" here
                os.println(message.trim());
            }




        }
        /*
         * Close the output stream, close the input stream, close the socket.
         */
        os.close();
        is.close();
        clientSocket.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
      }
    }
  }

  /*
   * Create a thread to read from the server. (non-Javadoc)
   *
   * @see java.lang.Runnable#run()
   */
  public void run() {
    /*
     * Keep on reading from the socket till we receive "Bye" from the
     * server. Once we received that then we want to break.
     */
    String responseLine;
    try {
      while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(responseLine);
        if (responseLine.indexOf("*** Bye") != -1)
          break;
      }
      closed = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you expect people to go through hundreds of lines of code? Maybe you could reduce this to a minimal example that illustrates the problem?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was hoping some one was nice enough to pilot it to recreate the problem. I have listed the lines that are concerned. I do admit this is my first post.

Thank you for taking the time to comment, I will edit the post with a more concise segment of the code

Answer (score 0):

If readLine() returns a blank line, it is because the sender sent a blank line. If it returns null, the sender has closed the connection.

You're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply ! Yes, I have read this piece of documentation before also, but the next line is not blank. Also the readLine() is not consistently returning a blank String. Every maybe 1/10 it will return what I am expecting it to return which is a String being sent over from the server.

I am thinking it might be a concurrency problem ? I really do not know though. Any input will help ! I will keep trying to see if it is reading a Blank line

Comment: I agree. It is a concurrency problem. Few if any of those fields should be static for example, certainly not the socket or the streams. The client socket should not be a field in the server class at all: it should be a field in the spawned Runnable that handles the client connection.

Answer (score -1):

The method readLine of **DataInputStream** is **deprecated**. I don't know why you use it, normally if you use an IDE like eclipse you'll see this method crossed out.

You should use a BufferedReader instead as explained in the Java documentation itself, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29) is a link.

Comment: All true but it doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: Well in the javadoc they say  "This method does not properly convert bytes to characters". Someone should start by using correct methods.

Comment: Agreed, again, but this answer doesn't explain the problem. It should have been posted as a comment.